# ¿como hago ventana emergente desde xml?

Tags: xml, kotlin, popup

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de un libro en kotlin/android studio. Con los datos almacenados en XML, necesito añadir la función de ventanas emergentes, teniendo en cuenta que se repiten durante todo el libro, cada palabra 1 código, ¿cual sería la manera mas efectiva de hacerlo?

- usó un menú y 1 textview para todo el libro
- al presionar el código de la palabra, la ventana emergente presentaría la información.
- adjunto ejemplo[image: ¡]

Comment: Una opción, no se si la mejor, es crear un `layout` con el diseño que te gustaría mostrar. Luego, al presionar el **código** llamas al `layout` que creaste y muestras la información que se corresponda.

Comment: Como podría hacer para linkear tantas palabras tantas veces durante todo el libro, imagina que en un verso hay 10 palabras y 10 referencias hacia otras palabras.
*muchas gracias.

Comment: Yo crearía un `array` con todas esas palabras que serían linkeadas en un `string.xml`. Luego, en la actividad buscaría esas palabras en el texto y si existe le añadiría el link hacia tu ventana emergente. En el siguiente ejemplo [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32278705/11539923) puedes ver como hacer lo que te digo de buscar palabras. Ya luego solo te quedaría ejecutar el evento para que se muestre la ventana